# Getting the keyword as a parameter from Adwords using ValueTrack

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, google-ads, tracking, google-ads-valuetrack

I set up an AdWords campaign for website following the instructions for [Google AdWords ValueTrack](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en).  One of the things that it is supposed to be able to do is pass the keyword as a URL parameter using the code `{keyword}` in the URL.

I created a landing URL using the [Google Analytics URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en).  I put `{keyword}` into the "Campaign Term" field and it came out like this:

```
http://example.com/landing.html?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D&utm_content=my_content&utm_campaign=my_page
```

When I actually run the campaign, the keyword substitution isn't happening.   I'm getting the literal string `{keyword}` passed to my website.   I see it in my log files.  Why isn't the substitution working the way I would expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the brackets in `{keyword}` cannot be URL escaped with `%7B` and `%7D`.  When I put it though the Google Analytics URL builder it came out as `utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D`.  It really needs to be `utm_term={keyword}`.

I updated my campaign with a better URL:

```
http://example.com/landing.html?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term={keyword}&utm_content=my_content&utm_campaign=my_page
```

Now Google is substituting the keyword into the `utm_term` parameter when I get a click from this Adwords campaign.

Comment: Hi there, can we get the cpc of that keyword?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos if you have your own question, please use the "Ask Question" link at the top of the page.

Comment: Hi there, to be honest I just posted two questions, but this thread came as a suggested. You can view my questions here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77953/custom-parameters-on-keyword-level-and-all-others-landing-page-final-url-trac and here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77952/tracking-template-lpurl-takes-you-back-to-the-specified-final-url-how-does-it-w