# Does a third party tracking service have to redirect to the final URL specified by the AdWords lpurl parameter?

Tags: google-ads, google-ads-valuetrack

According to this article, https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6076199

When you define a final URL as your landing page, you can use URL options to manage your tracking and redirect information.

So, my website is example.com and the 3rd party service I use is called 3rdpartytracker.com
Let's say that I own the 3rdpartytracker website too.

```
http://www.3rdpartytracker.com/rd?keyword={_mykwid}&ad={creative}&url={lpurl}
```

Do I have to set a redirection script into 3rdpartytracker.com to send me back to the example.com?

Or it will take me automatically back?
I mean how does this work in a more technical approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third party tracker would have to a redirect to your site.  Google has designed it so that it can work with any redirect script that takes the redirect as a parameter.    The parameter name doesn't have to be `url`.  It could be something like:

```
http://3rdpartytracker.com/track?redirect_to={lpurl}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So for example if the 3rdpartytracker.com ends with the execution (save variables to database), you use a html or php code to redirect it back, right ?

Comment: Right, but redirects have to be implemented with a server side script such as PHP, so straight HTML won't cut it.