# Custom parameters on keyword level and all others (landing page, final url, tracking template) on Ad level?

Tags: google-ads, google-ads-valuetrack

my goal is to track the cost (or max cpc) of each keyword coming to my website.

1. That means I have to play a lot on keyword level, right?

So, as far as I know the solution is given from the "custom parameters" that you can add to the tracking template or final url.
In my scenario, I will use a tracking template that will save the custom parameters.

My concern is what should I fill in keyword/ad group level and what should I leave blank in keyword/ad group level

2. Can I pass the keyword cpc (or max cpc) through a custom parameter dynamically? If not dynamically, is it against the rules to write it manually ? for example shoes_cpc=020
3. For this, shall I fill the custom parameters in each keyword ?
4. If on a keyword level leave the landing page (final url) and tracking template empty, will it use the ad group values instead?

[image]

3. Shall I leave blank the "customer parameters" on ad group? If yes, it will make use of the keyword level "customer parameters" ?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [value track documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en) doesn't list any parameters for your CPC or cost.

Including the CPC as a parameter could be possible but:

- You'd have to update the URL every time you change bids.
- What you actually pay isn't the CPC.   You often pay less than the CPC.

Google expects you to get information about your costs by logging into your AdWords account.